# Not able to send email to more then 60 users be SPD workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, smtp, outgoing-email

I have created the SharePoint designer workflow (list workflow) on an online site.

In this workflow, I am sending emails to every user in one of the SharePoint group(`name: users`).

if the group has **more then 60** members mail not reached to the user(in single email thread).

Please, someone, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try sending email to Office 365 group instead of SharePoint group as mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/workflows/configured-workflow-fails-running) and check if it works for you.

Comment: Also check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/send-email-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4) useful documentation on sending email in workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Ganesh Sanap, it would be way lot more easy if users you meant to send an email is inside an O365 group, you will just have to put 1 single email (groups email) then it will send an email to every users that is a member to that group.

Anyways, If the process or your case of using an SP Group is inevitable, it would be better if you send more information or screenshot of the workflow action on how you are doing the setup so we can see whats happening in between. Base on the case, I GUESS, its an issue of a query on the SP Group but only retrieving 60 persons, somewhere in the request we could increase the no of results if you have included a $top parameters in the rest URL or we could have a recursive wf that will loop until users in the group will be retrieved.

Hope the concept helps! Happy Learning!

Comment: There is no query involved here. Simply assigned the SP user group into the SharePoint designer workflow mailbox(To address). eg,  Email to "group".

Answer (score 0):

Another easy workaround:
- Create a simple http queue trigger azure app
- Get the workflow to submit all those emails to the function queue, one by one.
- Get the function app to send your email.

You could probably run this just fine on the free azure service plan.